# How can I display the number of pledges made by each donor in ORACLE sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

Display the number of pledges made by each donor. Include the donor ID, first name, last name, and number of pledges.
Below is what I have so far, but it isn't working. It counts the total donors, which makes sense, but I need to count how many pledges each donor made.

```
select iddonor, firstname, lastname, (select distinct count(iddonor) from dd_pledge) as pledges from dd_donor;
```

Below are the tables needed:

```
CREATE TABLE DD_Donor (
idDonor number(4),
Firstname varchar2(15),
Lastname varchar2(30),
              Typecode CHAR(1),
Street varchar2(40),
City varchar2(20),
State char(2),
Zip varchar2(9),
Phone varchar2(10),
Fax varchar2(10),
Email varchar2(25),
              News char(1),
dtentered date DEFAULT SYSDATE,
CONSTRAINT donor_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(idDonor) );

CREATE TABLE DD_Pledge (
               idPledge number(5),
               idDonor number(4),
               Pledgedate DATE,
               Pledgeamt number(8,2),
               idProj number(5),
               idStatus number(2),
               Writeoff number(8,2),
               paymonths number(3),
               Campaign number(4),
               Firstpledge char(1),
               CONSTRAINT pledge_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(idPledge),
               CONSTRAINT pledge_idDonor_fk FOREIGN KEY (idDonor)
                       REFERENCES dd_donor (idDonor), 
               CONSTRAINT pledge_idProj_fk FOREIGN KEY (idProj)
                       REFERENCES dd_project (idProj),
               CONSTRAINT pledge_idStatus_fk FOREIGN KEY (idStatus)
                       REFERENCES dd_status (idStatus));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should join the tables and count.

```
select d.idDonor, d.Firstname, d.Lastname, count(*) count
from DD_Donor d
join DD_Pledge p
on d.idDonor=p.idDonor
group by (d.idDonor, d.Firstname, d.Lastname)
```

Please note that this only shows a count for donors with a pledge. Those without a pledge will not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work better?

```
select iddonor, firstname, lastname, count(dd_pledge.iddonor) 
from dd_donor 
    inner join dd_pledge on dd_doner.iddoner = dd_pledge.iddoner
group by firstname,lastname;
```